# Vue.js Modifiers Chain

Tags: vue.js, events, preventdefault, chain, modifier

I am new in Vue.js. I am reading docs, and can't understand one moment...

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

> Order matters when using modifiers because the relevant code is
> generated in the same order. Therefore using @click.prevent.self will
> prevent all clicks while @click.self.prevent will only prevent clicks
> on the element itself.

I can't understand what's mean'***Therefore using @click.prevent.self will prevent all clicks while @click.self.prevent will only prevent clicks on the element itself.***' Can anybody give an example with prevent default actions and show difference...

for example with links (`<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">@click.prevent.self="fn" or @click.self.prevent="fn" difference</a>`)

I know about event phases (capture, target and bubbling).

For example it can be useful in Bubbling phase:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

.root {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 50px
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

<div id="app">
    <div class="root" v-on:click="log('root')">root
        <div class="parent" v-on:click.self.stop="log('parent')">Parent
            <div class="child" v-on:click="log('child')">Child
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javasctipt">
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
      },
      methods: {
        log(message) {
          alert(message);
          console.log(message)
        }
      }
    })
</script>
```

If i click on child i'll get output:

```
child
root
```

Bubblig doesn't stopped! But if i click on parent bubbling stopped! It's helpful!

But can anybody show me examples and difference if i'll use prevent and self modifiers (with links, checkboxes or may be with another elements) ?

Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can check this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/39994/

If you use `@click.prevent.self`, you can't click on anything. It prevents all click.
If you use `@click.self.prevent`, it only prevents when you click on `<a>` element, we can still click on choose file to upload file

Answer (score 0):

**Example illustrates difference in chain order**

```
<div id="app">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" @click.self.prevent target="_blank">Stackofervlow!
    <span :style="{ background: 'yellow', width: '100px', height: '100px' }">span</span>
  </a>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

**@click.self.prevent**

> 1. If you click on **span**, stackoverflow will open.
> 2. If you click on **a**, stackoverflow will not open.

**@click.prevent**

> 1. If you click on **span**, stackoverflow will not open.
> 2. If you click on **a**, stackoverflow will not open.